# All client side app that interfaces with tinder API

Tags: angularjs, cors, tinder

I am trying to obtain the authorization token from the tinder endpoint but I keep running into the CORS restriction. However I am able to obtain the facebook token and user ID without any issues. I obtain the tokens with the FB.login() function and then immediately use `$http.post` to call the tinder api endpoint `https://api.gotinder.com/auth` passing it the `{facebook_token : "", facebook_id:""}`. But I obtain

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
>   My code flow resembles this

```
FB.login().then(
  $http.post('https://api.gotinder.com/auth',{
     facebook_token : FB_TOKEN,
     facebook_id : FB_ID
  }).success(function(data){

      console.log(data);
   })
)
```

Comment: You need to sent the post request with very specific headers, as it's not a public API.